# Want to cut off negative area in chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm now working on a chart that shows how much time user has spend. Of course the sum of time is no way negative(but can be zero). But when I use chart.js API draw the chart, it automatically smoothened the line. As the result, the line dives into the negative area as below(yellow one). 
[image]

But if I set "lineTension" option to zero, the chart looks weird. What I want is to eliminate the line under the x-axis like below:
[image]

Is this possible? Thanks!

Comment: reading [this](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/424) suggests the issue was resolved 2 years ago - are you using the latest version

Comment: Yep, I think I downloaded the newest release. Seems like the issue appears again ([link](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/pull/2948)) in recent version and got fixed just few days ago. Maybe this fix hasn't be included into the release version I downloaded.